# Eval Script not working for mongo db 3.0.2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, eval, mongodb-query

I have upgraded my MongoDB to 3.0.2 from 2.4.10. I am having the database `"abc"` with user as `"xt"`. I can able to do crud operation after authenticating using `db.authenticate()` but I am not able to run the `eval` command. It throws the error as

> Unauthorized not authorized on abc to execute command { $eval: "deleteDetails()" }

When I check the admin database  `system.users` collection for the database user is

```
{
    "_id" : "abc.xt",
    "user" : "xt",
    "db" : "abc",
    "credentials" : {
        "SCRAM-SHA-1" : {
            "iterationCount" : 10000,
            "salt" : "mydgFCRFo05wh616qw6g1g==",
            "storedKey" : "c8YfzCZZ1qqw2EM8MRDQugQFk4s=",
            "serverKey" : "4JVLAIevhbJI6PtdDRRbelJa4pU="
        }
    },
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "abc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone tell, what may be the problem and also I saw that eval is deprecated, if so what can be the alternative for using in both mongo shell and node js.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2.6 they made the eval command require superuser access to the database so as a dbOwner you don't have enough access.  I'm researching this myself and I believe the command/runCommand might work to replace eval since it is now deprecated.